# Does anyone know if this(Lightweight Task Scheduling for .net /Silverlight) can be used on a shared hosting site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, shared-hosting

I found this( http://scheduling.codeplex.com/) and I can't find if this can be used on a shared hosting site. I am not sure if this is just some wrapper that wraps around the windows scheduler or if it is some library that sort of mimics the windows scheduler and can be used on a shared hosting site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can run on Silverlight, it can run on shared hosting.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Does it use windows scheduler now?

Comment: @chobo: If it works on Silverlight, it cannot _possibly_ use Windows Task Scheduler.  Silverlight applications cannot interact with the local system; there is (almost) nothing that you can do in Silverlight that you can't do in medium or low trust.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand. I don't know much about silver light.